# How to open another model when clicking on link inside modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I want to open the `SignIn` modal that inside the `SignIn` Component when clicking on `sign in` link which inside the `SignUp` component and do the same thing for the `SignUp`
This is the `Navbar` component's code which contains both of them

```
const Navbar :React.FC = () => { 
  const [isSignInModalOpen, setSignInModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isSignUpModalOpen, setSignUpModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  
  const openSignInModal = () => {
    setSignUpModalOpen(false);
    setSignInModalOpen(true);
  };

  const openSignUpModal = () => {
    setSignInModalOpen(false);
    setSignUpModalOpen(true);
  };
 
  console.log(isSignInModalOpen,'sign in');
  console.log(isSignUpModalOpen,'sign up');
return (
<div>
        <SignUp isOpen={isSignUpModalOpen} openSignInModal={openSignInModal} />
        <SignIn isOpen={isSignInModalOpen} openSignUpModal={openSignUpModal}/>
</div>
)}
```

And this is the `SignUp` component code

```
interface SignUpProps {
  mobile: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
  openSignInModal: ()=>void;
}
const SignUp: React.FC<SignUpProps> = ({openSignInModal,isOpen}) => {
  //  Default Modals 


  const [modal_standard, setmodal_standard] = useState<boolean>(isOpen);

  function tog_standard() {
    setmodal_standard(!modal_standard);
  }
 return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={() => tog_standard()}>
       sign up
      </Button>
      <Modal id="myModal"
          isOpen={modal_standard}
          toggle={() => {
            tog_standard();
          }} >
.....
              <ModalFooter>
                <p>
                  have already account
                  <span onClick={openSignInModal}> // here is where I want to open the another modal when clicing on it
                    sign in
                  </span>
                </p>
              </ModalFooter>
<>)}
export default SignUp
```

And finally, this is `SignIn` modal

```
 interface signinProps {
  mobile: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
  openSignUpModal: ()=>void;
}

const SignIn: React.FC<signinProps> = ({isOpen,openSignUpModal }) => {
  const [modal_standard, setmodal_standard] = useState<boolean>(isOpen);

  function tog_standard() {
    setmodal_standard(!modal_standard);
  }
 return (
<>
  <Button onClick={() => tog_standard()}>
   Sign In
  </Button>
  

      <Modal id="myModal"
        isOpen={modal_standard}
        toggle={() => {
          tog_standard();
        }}>
       ......
      <ModalFooter>
            <Button
              color="light">
              Sign in
            </Button>
            <p>
              don't have account?
              <span style={{ color: '#827E4A',cursor:'pointer' }} onClick={openSignUpModal}>
                create new account
              </span>
            </p>
     </ModalFooter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `SignUp` component. when you click on to Sign in button, the state `isSignUpModalOpen` is changed to `false`. but the state `modal_standard` is not updated and its value still is `true` (the `SignUp` modal is not closed). you need to add an `useEffect` to update it whenever the `isSignUpModalOpen` is updated.
for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setmodal_standard(isOpen)
}, [isOpen])
```

The `SignUp` component changed to the following:

```
interface SignUpProps {
mobile: boolean;
isOpen: boolean;
openSignInModal: ()=>void;
}
const SignUp: React.FC<SignUpProps> = ({openSignInModal,isOpen}) => {
//  Default Modals 

const [modal_standard, setmodal_standard] = useState<boolean>(isOpen);

useEffect(() => {
    setmodal_standard(isOpen)
}, [isOpen])

function tog_standard() {
  setmodal_standard(!modal_standard);
}
return (
  <>
    <Button
      onClick={() => tog_standard()}>
     sign up
    </Button>
    <Modal id="myModal"
        isOpen={modal_standard}
        toggle={() => {
          tog_standard();
        }} >
 .....
            <ModalFooter>
              <p>
                have already account
                <span onClick={openSignInModal}> // here is where I want to open the another modal when clicing on it
                  sign in
                </span>
              </p>
            </ModalFooter>
<>)}
export default SignUp
```

And also add one in the `SignIn` component.

Comment: its still not working

Comment: what happens when click on sign-in button? Has not anything happened?